# python gtk multi window

Tags: python, linux, window, gtk, multi-window

i have a big problem (for me!) with python gtk module.

i can open multi windows; but i can't close singly ( one time , one window ).
if i close a window, all windows close automatically. 
i want to close the first  window only. after closing firt window, come a new window ( by my choice).

for example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require20()
import gtk

class CLS1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mywindow = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.mywindow.connect("delete_event", gtk.main_quit)

        self.btn = gtk.Button("Cls1|Btn")

        self.mywindow.add(self.btn)

        self.mywindow.show_all()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

class CLS2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mywindow = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.mywindow.connect("delete_event", gtk.main_quit)

        self.btn = gtk.Button("Cls2|Btn")

        self.mywindow.add(self.btn)

        self.mywindow.show_all()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()


class APP(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mywindow = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.mywindow.connect("delete_event", gtk.main_quit)

        self.hori = gtk.HBox()

        self.btn1 = gtk.Button("AppBtn1")
        self.btn2 = gtk.Button("AppBtn2")

        self.btn1.connect("clicked", self.show_me , "AppBtn1")

        self.btn2.connect("clicked", self.show_me , "AppBtn2")

        self.hori.pack_start(self.btn1)
        self.hori.pack_start(self.btn2)

        self.mywindow.add(self.hori)

        self.mywindow.show_all()


    def show_me(self, penar, data):
        if data=="AppBtn1" :
            CLS1().main()

        if data=="AppBtn2":
            CLS2().main()

        gtk.main_quit()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

APP().main()
```

i want this :

1- i will run the program

2- the "APP" class will work and will come "APP" window

3- if i click a button (AppBt1 or AppBtn2) ; the "APP" window will close (automatically ; not by me!)

4- if i was clicked "AppBtn1" button on "APP" window (@step 3) ; the  "CLS1" class will work and its window will open

,or if i was clicked "AppBtn2" button on "APP" window (@step 3) ; the  "CLS2" class will work and its window will open

i wanna only one window on the screen while program running; if i click a button ; its window will close and a new window will open (by my choice, and automatically!)

how can i do this? and can you write its code :)
thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Calling gtk.main_quit will kill the whole program (it basically stop GTK). So what you need, is just to stop GTK *when the last window has been closed*. What you're currently doing is stopping GTK when any window is closed.

So just use a global variable that you will use as a counter of the windows open. On the delete-event handler, decrement that counter, and if it reached 0 that means you have no more windows open, and you can call gtk.main_quit, otherwise, do nothing and the window will just be normally destroyed.

To kill the parent window, just pass the parent as the last parameter when you connect to the `clicked` signal. In the associated callback, you'll get that last parameter and call gtk.Widget.destroy on it.

Answer (score 1):

Well a better way might be to modify the window that's already open instead of closing it and opening another.